# Laravel, extract certain data in an array

Tags: php, laravel

How to get the data(only the date) on the highlighted area as shown in picture below?

```
foreach($row as $key => $value)
{
  //what should I dd() here?
}
```

[image: array]

Comment: Could you try ```$value[1]->toDateString()```?

Comment: check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-pluck

Comment: @CUGreen great that works perfectly, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the keys, just do

```
foreach($row[1]->toDateString() as $date) {
    // do something here with $date
}
```

Otherwise, just `$value[1]->toDateString()`;